# Coffeescript Glob To Multiple with multipe cwd and dest

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I have such CoffeeScript Config inside my `gruntfile.js`:

```
coffee: {
  glob_to_multiple: {
      expand: true,
      flatten: false,
      cwd: 'server/api',
      src: ['**/*.coffee'],
      dest: 'server/api',
      ext: '.js',
      extDot: 'last'
  }
}
```

I want to add another directory, e.g. `cwd: 'server/config'` and destination should be `dest: 'server/config'` for that respectively. How to achieve?

Comment: Is this a Grunt config?

Comment: Yes it is a grunt config file.

Answer (score 2):

Define another coffee subtask:

```
coffee: {
  glob_to_multiple: {
      expand: true,
      flatten: false,
      cwd: 'server/api',
      src: ['**/*.coffee'],
      dest: 'server/api',
      ext: '.js',
      extDot: 'last'
  },

  other_stuff: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: false,
    cwd: 'server/config',
    src: ['**/*.coffee'],
    dest: 'server/api',
    ext: '.js',
    extDot: 'last'
  }
}
```

`grunt coffee` would run both tasks, `grunt coffee:glob_to_multiple` would just run the first.